# VLC won't open - undefined symbol: pl_Get

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, vlc

Some time ago I had installed VLC and it played without a single problem. Then, seeing that it was a 2.1.x version, I decided to update it to 2.2.x so that I could use the VLSub plugin. So I followed the commands shown in a few sites, but since then it has never worked again. The icon is shown and it is definitely installed, however, it just won't start.

I have tried uninstalling and installing it multiple times without any luck. I have done this through the Software Centre and via terminal. I have also tried purging the files and deleting any folders related to vlc I could find, namely /.config/vlc or /.vlc ( I also found a vlc folder in /usr/lib but I was afraid of deleting it).

I suppose the only help I have got is this, when trying to run it through terminal:

```
stephen@Event-Horizon:~$ vlc
VLC media player 2.1.4 Rincewind (revision 2.1.4-0-g2a072be)
vlc: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libvlc.so.5: undefined symbol: pl_Get
```

I could really use your help, since smplayer tends to display a lot of tearing (any help with that also welcome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of a [known bug](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=119043), but should be fixed by know.

Update your system and it should run fine:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If not you can use `sudo vlc --reset-config` to reset the config to it's defaults which should work too.

Comment: Upgrading solved the problem. Works fine!