# VLC player won't open

Tags: vlc, repository

I tried to get vlc 2.2, so that I could run vlsub. In terminal, I entered `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily` followed by `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install vlc`.

VLC appears in my dock and in applications, but it cannot open now.

What is the problem? Did I add updates from the repository that I shouldn't have? How can I close it and revert back to my older version of VLC?

Comment: what happens when you run in a terminal `vlc`?

Comment: Terminal outputs the following: **VLC media player 2.1.4 Rincewind (revision 2.1.4-0-g2a072be) vlc: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libvlc.so.5: undefined symbol: pl_Get**

Comment: does this help http://askubuntu.com/questions/503860/vlc-wont-open-undefined-symbol-pl-get ?

Comment: I have another problem now with VLC. The software center did an automatic upgrade to packages, and deleted VLC from my entire system. Now I cannot download it. When I try downloading in Terminal with the command **sudo apt-get install vlc-nox**, it outputs: **Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.**

Comment: It follows with: **The following information may help resolve the situation: The following packages have unmet dependencies: vlc-nox : Depends : libavcodec55 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not installable or libavcodec-extra-55 (>= 6:10~~git20131218.b3189af~ubuntu14.04.1) but it is not installable**

Comment: **Depends: libavformat55 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not installable**

Comment: **Depends: libavutil53 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not installable**

Comment: Finally: **E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.**

Comment: sudo apt-get -f install

Answer (score 1):

Yay, I fixed it on my own! I just removed the repository I added above and updated with the commands: `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/videolan-* && sudo apt-get update` .

Comment: Awesome, feel free to mark your answer as thee answer :).